# In Visual Studio 2022, why are my F# projects looking for "FSharp.Core with version (>= 6.0.2), which doesn't exist?

Tags: f#, .net-5, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I have a set of F# projects in a solution.  They're all .NET 5.0 projects.

I recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2022, Version 17.1.0 Preview 1.0.

Now when I build, I get errors about FSharp.Core, as pictured below.

The errors are in principle correct; the latest version of [FSharp.Core on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Core) is 6.0.1.

What I've tried:

- I've searched my project for "FSharp.Core" and "6.0.2" and other such things but haven't found anything.
- I've edited the project files but haven't found anything relevant.
- When I build from the command line using `dotnet build`, I get no errors or warnings.
- I tried changing `net5.0` to `net6.0` in each project file, but I still got the same errors.

Why is Visual Studio 2022 wanting to restore a version of FSharp.Core that doesn't exist?

[image: Unable to find package FSharp.Core with version (>= 6.0.2)]

Comment: This looks like bug in sdk, you should report it in [repository](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp). For now, you can try to fix this by changing property `FSCorePackageVersion` in `Microsoft.FSharp.NetSdk.props` inside sdk located in `c:/Program Files/dotnet/sdk/your_version/fsharp`. Or you can set it inside project file

Comment: @JL0PD Is the F# repo the right place to report it if it only happens in Visual Studio?

Comment: There's a VS 2022 bug reported about it: [NU1102 Unable to find package FSharp.Core with version (>= 6.0.2)](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/NU1102-Unable-to-find-package-FSharpCor/1576726)

Comment: Did you find a decent workaround? If not, I might have one or two ideas based on past experiences.

Comment: @BentTranberg Nope, not yet.  Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Try any of these: Set FSharp.Core reference to v 6.0.0 (will likely work), or 6.0.1 (unlikely, but try), or try to remove the reference altogether. Also, VS can fail to pick up these particular changes in an editing session, or even after restart, so a full measure is to delete bin and obj and .vs folders and restart VS to get around that before doing a Rebuild.

Comment: Thanks, @BentTranberg.  When I used NuGet in VS 2022 to manually install FSharp.Core 6.0.1 in each F# project, the problem went away.

Comment: @BentTranberg You should add that as an answer/workaround.

Comment: That jogs my memory. I remember that just editing 6.0.2 to 6.0.0 or 1 didn't work, and I had to go "the official route" to have it work, just like you did. I don't think "Restore Packages" worked either, but it's possible it worked or could have worked following a restart of VS. I wasn't sure which measure helped me back then, but I think you've found and pointed to the actual solution that also likely helped me.